# Can't modify value passed by ref in other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I was trying to demo to a collegue why you'd better pass const references to functions doing read only operations with the following code. To my surprise it prints "It's safe!", even if I'm changing the value of the `passedBool` while the other thread is sleeping.

I'm trying to find out if I made a typo somewhere, if the compiler optimizes the code and passes `passedBool` by copy to avoid some overhead or if starting another thread creates a local copy of `passedBool`.

```
class myClass
{
public:
  myClass(bool& iBool)
  {
    t = thread(&myClass::myMethod,this,iBool);
  }

  ~myClass()
  {
    t.join();
  }

private:
  thread t;

  void myMethod(bool& iBool)
  {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    if(iBool)
      cout << "It's safe!" << endl;
    else
      cout << "It's NOT safe!!!" << endl;
  }
};


void main()
{
  bool passedBool = true;

  cout << "Passing true" << endl;
  myClass mmyClass(passedBool);  

  cout << "Changing value for false" <<endl;
  passedBool = false;

  cout << "Expect \"It's NOT safe!!!\"" <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If
>   a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has
>   to be wrapped (e.g. with std::ref or std::cref).

[from here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

Comment: it's interesting... when changing the thread initialization with the `std::cref()` wrapper and changing the arguments types for `const bool& passedBool` I'm reaching the "not safe" state, as if the initial passedBool was never cast as const

Comment: I think, const modifier here is to prevent child thread procedure to modify value. it's like calling func(const bool& val). func can't modify val, but caller can.